# Last day of month (no timestamp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create two dynamic dates in html/javascript/jquery. I want the dates to be formatted like yyyy/mm/dd. The first date will return the last day of the previous month, and the second date will return the last day of the current month. Anyone know how to do this in the technologies listed above?

I am 99.9999% positive I can accomplish this by making a call to a backend page using C#, but I want to see if there is a more efficient way to do this right in the DOM (is DOM the correct terminology?).

From a previous question on SO, here is the code I am using now...

```
var d = new Date();
document.write(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you already have most of the answer:

```
var d = new Date();
var lastcurrent = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59);
var lastprevious = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 0, 23, 59, 59);
```

Then to format them how you want you can use:

```
document.write(lastcurrent.getFullYear() + '/'
               + (lastcurrent.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + lastcurrent.getDate());
document.write(lastprevious.getFullYear() + '/' 
               + (lastprevious.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + lastprevious.getDate());
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrwaA/).

**Edit**
With two-digit month (last day should always be two digits):

```
document.write(lastcurrent.getFullYear()
               + '/' + String('00'+(lastcurrent.getMonth() + 1) ).slice(-2)
               + '/' +  lastcurrent.getDate() );
document.write(lastprevious.getFullYear()
               + '/' + String('00'+ (lastprevious.getMonth() + 1) ).slice(-2)
               + '/' + lastprevious.getDate());
```

Comment: in the last line of code in your edit, I believe lastcurrent.getDate() should be lastprevious.getDate(). Am I right?

Comment: @Ant - Yes. Sorry, copy & paste got me. :P I've fixed it now.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help! I would've edited it myself, but I don't have enough privilege to edit answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
var today = new Date();

var lastofpreviews = new Date( today.getUTCFullYear(), today.getUTCMonth()    , 0 );
var lastofthis     = new Date( today.getUTCFullYear(), today.getUTCMonth() + 1, 0 );
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/GW9B9/

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
document.write(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 0, 23, 59, 59).toLocaleFormat('%Y/%m/%d'));
document.write(new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59).toLocaleFormat('%Y/%m/%d'));
```

This will format the dates in the requested format (YYYY/mm/dd)

Comment: I don't think that method is widely supported.

Comment: According to Netbeans is should work in all mainstream browsers and even IE6. I don't have all those browsers available to test with, so I just have to assume that Netbeans is correct.

Comment: I just tested it in Opera, IE8, Safari 3 (Win), Chrome and FF3. It only worked in FF. Test code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbunX/) if you want to try too.

Comment: The code is working in FF4 too, but not in Chromium. Guess it is not as widespread as Netbeans made me believe.